# How to zip / archive hidden files using Compress-Archive?

Tags: powershell, compression, zip, hidden-files

When zipping folders using [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/Compress-Archive?view=powershell-5.1) it skips all hidden files.

The Documentation page tells us that this cmdlet uses Microsoft .NET Framework API [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=netframework-4.7.2) in the background.

Is there some way to force it to archive hidden files?  I cannot find this issue documented anywhere. I tried `-Force` for the heck of it, didn't help.

My current workaround is to use `Set-FileAttribute` to remove the hidden attribute before zipping.

Comment: I thought `Get-ChildItem -Path '...' -Force | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath '...'` would be the solution, but that throws a `Get-Item : Could not find item ...` error with the path of one of the hidden files.

Comment: Thought adding the force parameter to Compress-Archive would fix this too, same errors using `Compress-Archive $test.fullname -Force -DestinationPath test.zip`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a bug/oversight in the `Compress-Archive` cmdlet.  Since the cmdlet provides no "include hidden files" parameter but does accept a collection of source files via the `-Path` or `-LiteralPath` parameters, I would expect either this...

```
Compress-Archive -Path (
    Get-ChildItem -Path '...' -Force `
        | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'FullName' `
) -DestinationPath '...'
```

...or this...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '...' -Force | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath '...'
```

...to work as a way of passing hidden files to the cmdlet; the key being specifying the `-Force` parameter for `Get-ChildItem`.  Both of those invocations, however, throw these errors...

```
Get-Item : Could not find item ....
At C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:814 char:63
+ ... Entry.LastWriteTime = (Get-Item -LiteralPath $currentFilePath).LastWr ...
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (...:String) [Get-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand

Exception setting "LastWriteTime": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTimeOffset"."
At C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:814 char:25
+ ...             $currentArchiveEntry.LastWriteTime = (Get-Item -LiteralPa ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

...for the first hidden file in the input list.  (Note that invoking the first snippet without `Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'FullName'` instead throws `Compress-Archive : The path '...' either does not exist or is not a valid file system path.`.)

On my system, [the referenced lines](https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/blob/v1.1.0.0/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1#L828) 812-814 of `Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1` are...

```
# Updating  the File Creation time so that the same timestamp would be retained after expanding the compressed file. 
# At this point we are sure that Get-ChildItem would succeed.
$currentArchiveEntry.LastWriteTime = (Get-Item -LiteralPath $currentFilePath).LastWriteTime
```

So, even if we pass `-Force` to `Get-ChildItem` to get the paths of hidden file objects to pass to `Compress-Archive`, internally the cmdlet is fetching those file objects again using `Get-Item`...but it's not passing `-Force`, which of course will fail (despite what the comment on the previous line claims).  Thus, I don't think there's any way to get `Compress-Archive` to work with hidden files without either you or Microsoft editing that script.

Comment: Looks like an issue needs to be raised for this: https://github.com/powershell/powershell/issues

Comment: @JamesC. I raised the issue

Comment: I opened [an issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues/66) for this in the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive` GitHub repository](https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive) as well.

Comment: Still not included in any Powershell release as far as I know.  I created an Issue at [PowerShell/PowerShell#21136](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/21136)

Answer (score 7):

I replaced `Compress-Archive` with [`\[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory(sourceDirectoryName, destinationArchiveFileName)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.createfromdirectory) and found (on macOS at least) that the ZIP-file included a directory that starts with `.` (which is one way to hide a directory/file on macOS). This is using PowerShell 7.2.

Comment: I've tested using [system.io.compression.zipfileextensions.createentryfromfile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions.createentryfromfile?view=net-6.0) on Windows and it compressed hidden files, as long as you use the `-Force` parameter to `Get-ChildItem` so it finds the files.  In my tests the hidden attribute was not preserved in the archive. 
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70171826/archive-folder-without-some-subfolders-and-files-using-powershell/70173927#70173927) for an example that stores a path in the archive.

Comment: I can confirm that this works on OSX/PS7 and this is an excellent workaround until `Compress-Archive` is updated to handle hidden files.

Answer (score 3):

I've just had the same issue and this is how I got aroung it

```
# WARNING: This only works on a windows based powershell core terminal instance.
# In a linux based powershell core instance the .dot files are not included in 
# the final archive when using the -Filter example

# This will include .files like .gitignore
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter *.* | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath dist.zip

# This will include .dot files like .gitignore and any that are hidden like .git
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Force | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath dist.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Well ...that's really annoying then!
I've taken to using 7-Zip via Powershell but of course that does mean I'm using yet another tool. It also means it's almost redundant using Compress-Archive.

Here's part of my script delcaring the 7Zip variables and zipping stuff:

```
    $7ZipPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    
    If (-Not (Test-Path -Path $7ZipPath -PathType Leaf)) {
        throw "7 Zip File '$7ZipPath' Not Found"
    PAUSE
    }
    
    Set-Alias 7Zip $7ZipPath 
    
    $ItemsToZip = @{
    Path= "$TempDirectory\*"
    CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
    DestinationPath = $MyZipFile
    
    Compress-Archive @ItemsToZip
    
    7zip u $MyZipFile -ux2y2z2 "C:\Path\HiddenFile.ext"
```

Hope that helps someone